# bullet chart in Angular with d3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I use [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) code to create a bullet chart with d3. Now I want to create a bullet chart in an Angular component.
I'm new to d3 so i tried to convert the code to typescript.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/h4xx0gus/1/) is my code. I know there are mistakes in the code. Could you help me to make it working?

```
this.svg = d3.select('body').selectAll('svg')
  .enter().append('svg')
  .attr('class', 'bullet')
  .attr('width', 100 + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
  .attr('height', 300 + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom);

this.g = this.svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')')
;
```

This is the svg init function. I should create a svg element in the dom, but it doesn't.
In the example `.attr('class', 'bullet')` does the work. But this will not work in angular.
Any ideas?

Comment: @ A. Blom...Can you please create a working plunker for bullet Chart, so that it may help.

Comment: Where do you put 'bullet.js' in angular2 app.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.selectAll('svg').enter()`. Enter only works after a `.data()` join. Have a look at [Mike Bostock's *Thinking with Joins*](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!